# Bug Adding Group to Existing Team Site

Tags: error, groups, team-sites

We're seeing a strange error while trying to create a Group on an existing Team site.

```
Property classification has an invalid value
```

[image]

I tried removing all Owners and Members and just adding myself, but the error still appears and won't let me create the Group. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does it give you the same error if you add users from the Teams App?  What about when you add owners & members to the group in Azure?

Comment: The Group doesn't exist yet so it's not in Azure. It wouldn't have an associated Team until this step is complete.